# Sorting and Paging with MVC 5 ADO.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

I've the following code:

1. Model

   ```
   public int ManufactureID { get; set; }

   public string Manufacture { get; set; }

   public string ManufactureDescription { get; set; }

   public bool IsActive { get; set; }
   ```
2. Controller

   ```
   public ActionResult ManufactureIndex(string manufacture = "")
   {
       ManufactureRepository ManufactureRepo = new ManufactureRepository();
       ModelState.Clear();
       ViewBag.sManufacture = manufacture;
       return View(ManufactureRepo.ManufactureGetAll(manufacture));
   }
   ```
3. Repository

   ```
   private SqlConnection con;
   //To Handle connection related activities
   private void Connection()
   {
       con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ITPCNMSCon"].ToString());
   }

   //To view employee details with generic list
   public List<Manufactures> ManufactureGetAll(string manufacture = "")
   {
       Connection();
       List<Manufactures> EmpList = new List<Manufactures>();
       SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("_spManufactureGet", con)
       {
           CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
       };
       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(manufacture))
       {
           com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Manufacture", DBNull.Value);
       }
       else
       {
           com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Manufacture", manufacture);
       }
       SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
       DataTable dt = new DataTable();
       con.Open();
       da.Fill(dt);
       con.Close();

       //Bind EmpModel generic list using LINQ 
       EmpList = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows

                  select new Manufactures()
                  {
                      ManufactureID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ManufactureId"]),
                      Manufacture = Convert.ToString(dr["Manufacture"]),
                      ManufactureDescription = Convert.ToString(dr["ManufactureDescription"]),
                      IsActive = Convert.ToBoolean(dr["IsActive"])
                  }).ToList();
       return EmpList;
   }
   ```
4. Store Procedure

   ```
   SELECT      *
   FROM        _Manufacture
   WHERE       Manufacture = ISNULL(@Manufacture,Manufacture)
   ORDER BY    Manufacture
   ```

My question is, I want to provide a sorting and paging on the view using sql connection. How can I do that? Please advise.

Thank you.

Comment: Your stored procedure should be getting page number and returning fixed number of rows.

Comment: @derloopkat, I didn't get it. I want to add a paging and sorting on the view. At least, paging. Let say, 10 records per page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all the answer. I have my own answer. I am following below tutorial to create sorting and paging.

[Sorting, Filtering, and Paging with the Entity Framework in an ASP.NET MVC Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Really appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 int pageSize = 10;
 int skip = 0;
 int recordsTotal = 0;
```

Where **pagesize** is number of records that you want to display in grid,
**skip** is starting point to pick the records,**recordsTotal**  total number of records in grid.

```
  recordsTotal = EmpList.Count();
  EmpList= EmpList.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass page number and number and number of records you want to fetch per request.

```
@PageNumber int
@Records int


Declare @StartingPoint int, @EndingPoint int
Set @StartingPoint = ((@PageNumber -1 ) * @Records)+1
Set @EndingPoint = @PageNumber  * @Records
Select * from (
  Select Dense_Rank() over(order by <PK>) Order,* from <Table>
)TempRecord where [Order]>= @StartingPoint  and [Order]<=@EndingPoint
```

So now when you call this store procedure pass PageNumber and Records parameter value

When you pass 1 for PageNumber and 10 for Records StartingPoint will be 1 and EndingPoint will be 10 so you get 10 records Similarly for Page 2 StartingPoint will be 11 and EndingPoint will be 20 thus you will get 10 records.